# Given a function $f \colon I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, that has a limit ${L}$. Does the limit $|{L}|$ exist for |f|?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I did the following:

Given $f(t) = (f^1(t),\dots,f^n(t)),\ f^i \in \mathbb{R}$, the limit $\lim_{t \rightarrow t_0} f(t) ={L}$ existing implies that for $f^i$, $\forall \varepsilon,$ $\exists \delta$ s.t. $|t-t_0| < \delta \implies |f^i(t)-f^i(t_0)| < \varepsilon$. Now, given that $||a|-|b||\leq|a-b|$, the existence of  $\lim_{t \rightarrow t_0} |f(t)| =|{L}|$ is guaranteed. If true, this is analogous to the single variable case.

However, I don't know if it's true. I understand there are some constructions in topology that might aide me, but I'm not well versed in them and I can't think of a counter example. Am I correct or not?

Cheers!

Comment: Reverse triangle inequality proves the result. No difference between $n=1$ and $n>1$.

Comment: Yes it is true, because any norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$ also satisfies the triangle inequality (by definition), and hence also satisfies the reverse triangle inequality ($\|a\|=\|(a-b)+b\|\leq \|a-b\|+\|b\|$, and hence $\|a\|-\|b\|\leq \|a-b\|$. By interchanging $a,b$ we see that $\bigg| 
\|a\|-\|b\| \bigg|\leq \|a-b\|$).

Comment: Great! I'm more familiar w single variable real analysis, but I'm cautious about the MV case

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $g$ is continuous, then $g(f(x))$ is continuous at $a$.  In this case, $g= \vert \cdot \vert$, which is continuous.